# How to release hung licenses from the client side?

Tags: abaqus, flexlm

abaqus floating licenses gets hung. For example: if I kill a running job, the tokens that were previously in use (by me) gets hung and if I submit a job again there are no tokens available. When I check the token usage with ***abaqus licensing ru***, it's my machine that’s using the tokens but no other job is running and no one else is using.

At the moment I’m restarting my machine to free up the tokens. Sometimes (Close to all) restart also doesn't help. ***Simulia Knowledgebase*** is not of much help.

I also checked whether the **lmgrd.exe** and **ABAQUSLM** is running in the process, apparently not. I don't have access to the server, How the client can purge the licenses, which the client checked out?

Comment: try shutting down with `abaqus terminate`

Comment: In my experience, often there's a `python.exe` process that survives the kill command that's holding the license, and it sometimes won't let go even during a shutdown (which causes a ghost license you'll need the license server manager to release).  Kill those processes in process manager and usually the licenses come back.

Answer (score 2):

From the client side, it must be used the command 'lmutil' :

```
 ./lmutil lmremove --help
 lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2014 Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 usage:     lmremove [-c licfile] feature user host display
            lmremove [-c licfile] -h feature host port handle
            lmremove [-c licfile] [-tsborrow <client_host>] | [-tsborrowstat]
```

For the 'licfile' parameter, you can use `<server port>@<server name>`.

But all users can't do that. Under Linux (I suppose under Windows to) the user that use this command must belong to the 'lmadmin' group on the licenses server.

A good solution is to use the 'TIMEOUT' directive in the option file if Abaqus's vendor daemon authorize this. 'TIMEOUT' define a delay. If a token isn't used during this delay, the server get it (an automatic 'IN' is done) and the token is free for an other user or the same when needed.

The license administrator can forbid this user action. It's very dangerous because all services licenses can be shut down by all members of the 'lmadmin' group. There is now way to limit the user's privileges if he belongs to the 'lmadmin' group on the licences server.

The simple solution is to ask to your licences administrator to release the token. In some case, there is no other solution than stop and restart the licences service.